# numpy array summary with for loop

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, for-loop

I have a lot of txt, I want to read it, and plus them(every txt have same shape of array)

```
    for i in base_n:
        dfp_base=np.loadtxt(base_n,skiprows=2,usecols=(1,2,3))
        dfp_base+=dfp_base
    print dfp_base
```

but it's will only plus the end of files

I try to assign a variable but it's will give me an error

```
    for i in base_n:
        dfp_base=np.loadtxt(base_n,skiprows=2,usecols=(1,2,3))
        dfp_base_s+=dfp_base
    print dfp_base_s

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'dfp_base_s' referenced before assignment
```

how to fix it?

**EDIT**
i define a zero array and solve this problem

```
dfp_base_s=np.zeros(shape=(30,3))
```

Comment: Did you forget to initialize `dfp_base_s` ?

Comment: the anwser is right! I need to define dfp_base_sat  first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your problem that you are trying to assign to var that not `referenced before assignment`
 see on below:

```
for i in range(1,10): 
     dfp_base=1 
     dfp_base_s+=dfp_base 



NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-24596062a447> in <module>
      1 for i in range(1,10):
      2      dfp_base=1
----> 3      dfp_base_s+=dfp_base
      4 

NameError: name 'dfp_base_s' is not defined
```

but if you initialize before the loop that will work

```
 dfp_base_s = 0              

 for i in range(1,10): 
      dfp_base=1 
      dfp_base_s+=dfp_base 


 dfp_base_s                  
 9
```